# How to get only the number from a string with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings like " $250.00", " $100.00" , " $1000.88", " $75.00" and I would like to get just the numbers with the period in the middle.
i.e.: "250.00"     "100.00"    "1000.88"     "75.00"

Also, the $ could be another currency. Not necessarily $. 
So, I just need to get numbers and period.

I tried with some regular expressions that I know but couldn't do it.

```
var initialPrice = " $250.00" // I need just 250.00
```

I need to get rid of the spaces if possible. 
I just need the numbers and the period.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I need the period too.

Comment: It's easy to add period after you have the `int` value. Choose whatever is best suited for your needs! I just posted the link here cuz it might help other ppl.

Comment: It's a simple thing. If you don't have spaces between, its just `[\d.]+`. If you have spaces, replace all whitespace with blank first. It's easier that you don't have to validate the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:\d+\.\d+)
```

1. Find 1 or more integers until you find a period
2. match the period
3. match 1 or more digits after the period

This is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aaBfpK/3)

This is how you might want to do this in javascript.

```
var initialPrice = " $250.00" // I need just 250.00
var v = initialPrice.match(/(?:\d+\.\d+)/)[0];
console.log(v);
```

Comment: @sln good catch, fixed.

Comment: Thank you but where should I put the expression? inside a match test replace?? If you help me, I'll be gratefull.

Comment: @dragon25 are you trying to parse a script?

Comment: yes, that's the final expectation

Comment: @dragon25 updated answer.